# MongoDB: hint index in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-indexes

MongoDB version 3.0.6

Im performing multiple queries were I discovered that they use the wrong index. I guess there is `USE INDEX()` or `hint()` for mongo, but I cant find it in the documentation. I'm using java. One of the queries looks like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(
    new Document()
         .append("timestamp", new Document()
                 .append("$gte", startTime)
                 .append("$lte", endTime))
);
```

...where I want the query to use an index I created named `timestamp`.

Comment: Have you tried to append a hint to your query? `.append("$hint", ...)`? In the source code of the class FindOperation which belongs to the new part of the driver.

Comment: I'm looking into it now. `.append("$hint","timestamp")` or something?

Comment: no banana when appending a hint on the findIterable. Anyone? I wonder why this simple task is so badly documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $hint of mongo.
For more detail refer

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/meta/hint/

Comment: By the way how do you concluded that mongo is using wrong index

Comment: by using .explain("executionStats") in the shell

Comment: and the site you linked to only shows the mongo shell syntax for using hint. Any idea for java?

Comment: query.withHint("fieldName") used in spring mongoTemplate.